# Identifying the latest node using end_date field values using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement to identify the latest record from the child node based on the end_date value. As per the source XML data, end_date can be missing (not exist) or will be having values.  I need to pick the records based on this order /condition

a) if end_date field is missing (any one of the nodes) then should pick those records.
b) if end_date is filled (for all nodes) then need to pick the highest (latest date )

tried with the below code but its works only when end_date is existing and skipping those missing the records which having no end_Date.

```html
<xsl:for-each select="hm:job_information">
  <xsl:sort select="hm:end_date" data-type="text" order="descending" />
  <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <xsl:text>"business_unit":"</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="./hm:business_unit" />
    <xsl:text>"company":"</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="./hm:company" />
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

The below is the sample input file. i would like to record with 80004122 (as business_unit) as this records doesnt have any end date . If suppose both records (80004122,70001634) having end date then need to pick the one which has latest end date in it.

```html
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
  <queryResponse xmlns="urn:sfobject.sfapi.successfactors.com" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.sfapi.successfactors.com">
     <result>
        <sfobject>
           <id>18348</id>
           <type>CompoundEmployee</type>
           <person>
            <user_id>28009483</user_id>
                 <personal_information>
                     <first_name>Rodrigo</first_name>
                     <first_name_alt1>Rodrigo</first_name_alt1>
                     <formal_name>Rodrigo Lacey</formal_name>
                     <gender>M</gender>
                  </personal_information>   
                  <employment_information>
                      <job_information>
                        <business_unit>100</business_unit>
                        <company>11</company>
                        <start_date>2010-09-01</start_date>
                        <end_date>2013-08-01</end_date>
                      </job_information>
                      <job_information>
                        <business_unit>200</business_unit>
                        <company>22</company>
                        <start_date>2020-03-11</start_date>
                        <end_date>2021-08-01</end_date>
                      </job_information>
                      <job_information>
                        <business_unit>300</business_unit>
                        <company>33</company>
                        <start_date>2015-03-11</start_date>
                        <end_date>2016-10-01</end_date>
                      </job_information>
                </employment_information>
          </person>
           <execution_timestamp>2022-03-03T02:31:15.000Z</execution_timestamp>
           <version_id>2111P0</version_id>
        </sfobject>
        <numResults>1</numResults>
        <hasMore>false</hasMore>
        <querySessionId>c2172238-c6ed-4fd5-aa9a-6840a2fd1b26</querySessionId>
     </result>
  </queryResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:template match="employment_information">
    <xsl:variable name="max-date" select="max(job_information/xs:date(end_date))" />
    <xsl:variable name="last-job" select="(job_information[not(end_date)], job_information[end_date=$max-date])[1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$last-job/business_unit"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

> Can i do anything on the sort part ?

Yes, you could sort as follows:

```
<xsl:sort select="number(boolean(end_date))" data-type="number" order="ascending" />
<xsl:sort select="end_date" data-type="text" order="descending" />
```

Comment: thanks michael for the example will try it out , i just also want to double check on the sorting approach. Can i do anything on the sort part ?<xsl:sort select="hm:end_date" data-type="text" order="descending"/>  or its not an ideal approach. Im little knowledge in xslt

Comment: See the addition to my post.

Comment: Michael sorry for bothering again , when i tested second scenario. b) if end_date is filled (for all nodes) then need to pick highest (latest date ) is not working currectly . As per my understanding the solution above it will mark 0 when no end_date filed in the node and otherwise it set 1 . In the second sort it will sort based o and 1 ? is that my understanding is correct

Comment: It works for me - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aB9NKW.

Comment: Thanks Micheal , The provide link working fine and that exactly what i am looking for. My be i was not integrated correctly with my scripts , Will double check and update you soon . thanks for the helps again

Comment: sorry for the confusion , i think issue was with actual source file . The one i added in my original question i have kept only the part of nodes  (thought thats enough ). Now when i started explored realized that solution will work only when xml file is intact. Sorry for that, this was due to lack of my knowledge. if you could help me with solution on the latest xml then it will be great help.